# SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid'); not work

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osgeo

I'm using using OSgeo 6.5 dvd and studing pgrouting workshop ([link](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html#calculate-topology)) for get shortest path. I created network topology call "pgrouting - workshop". There are three commands to execute in section 5.2 they are :

```
-- Add "source" and "target" column
ALTER TABLE ways ADD COLUMN "source" integer;
ALTER TABLE ways ADD COLUMN "target" integer;

-- Run topology function
SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

Add source and target was executed successfully. topology function give errors.
Heres the error :

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
ERROR:  function startpoint(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT gid AS id, StartPoint(the_geom) AS source, EndPoint(t...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT gid AS id, StartPoint(the_geom) AS source, EndPoint(the_geom) as target FROM ways
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 27 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
```

How do i fix this error?

I loaded the legacy.sql and noted that error has little bit changed :

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
ERROR:  function point_to_id(geometry, double precision) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT point_to_id(setsrid(_r.source, srid), tolerance)
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT point_to_id(setsrid(_r.source, srid), tolerance)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 33 at assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of pgRouting installed on the OSGeo LiveDVD 6.5 is not fully working with PostGIS 2.0, but you can solve most issues by loading the `legacy.sql` file to your database:

```
\i /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.0/legacy.sql
```

In most cases when an errors occurse, pgRouting functions are missing the `ST_` prefix, for example `ST_StartPoint(the_geom)`.

Comment: I loaded the legacy.sql but issue was stil there. How do i add the ST_ prefix to  assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid'); Where should I add it? I think it must be like this SELECT "ST_assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');"

Comment: http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/common/doc/functions/create_topology.html if you use latest pgrouting. Or you can also create topology using (fastest method for big datasets) http://pgrouting.org/docs/howto/topology.html#grass